# hide file extension in url by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to hide my file extensions in browser to be displayed, like `http://www.example.com/dir/abc.php` should be displayed as `http://www.example.com/dir/abc` only.

i wrote following rewriteCond and rewrite rule on `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

but this code doeesn't seems to helping me.

EDIT:
this is complete code of my htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|png)$ - [F]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js|png|jpg)$ $1.$2 [L]

RewriteEngine On



# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Did you try to enable logging and see what you get? [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) or [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) is you use Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Answer (score 0):

#### COMPLETE .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php

RewriteEngine on 

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# block direct hot linking
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?127.0.0.1 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpg|png)$ - [F]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js|png|jpg)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Comment: what is external redirect and internal redirect?

Comment: there is a glitch in this code, this is working fine for root directory, but for internal directory, this is not working, like if i open `www.mysite.com/abc.php` it is working as `www.mysite.com/abc` but for internal directories like `www.mysite.com/dir/abc.php` it is giving `www.mysite.com/dir/abc/` which is resulting into 404

Comment: i am currently developing my site on apache localhost, and this is not working there

Comment: i edited my question, added .htaccess there, this is only .htaccess there, and this is in root directory itself

Comment: externally redirect working well if filename does NOT contain any space or -. If filename contain any - or space it is not working. If possible reply.

Comment: @NikhilsHETH: This is very old question. Post your problem in a separate question and we'll help you.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066877/how-externally-redirect-url-using-htaccess-when-url-contain-space-number-or-da

Answer (score 0):

easy method is:

```
you create your  link like
```

`'<a href="home">Home</a>'` instead of `'<a href="home.php">Home</a>'`
Then your .htaccess should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l
RewriteCond ^home home.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Apache expert by any stretch, but I'm curious why no one is recommending the negotiation module (mod_negotiation). Are there best-practice reasons to avoid using

I heard about it in passing at http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=317269. After enabling mod_negotiation in my global configuration:

```
LoadModule negotiation_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
```

I just had to enable it in my virtualhost's Options. Here's the whole config block:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site_directory/public_html
ServerName your.domain.here.com
<Directory /var/www/site_directory/public_html>
allow from all
Options +Indexes Multiviews
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```