# Show message after the interval time end?

Tags: php

Example the interval time is `30 minutes` and after `30 minutes` is exceeded, 
echo message `"You have been free from banned"`

How do I make it?

Comment: There is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658158/hide-file-extension-in-url-by-htaccess

Comment: are that working with .png?

Comment: Read the page stubben has provided to get that answer

Comment: There are too much code, please explain here...

Comment: I'd wish every coding problem I have could be solved with about 5 lines of code. Don't be lazy

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.png)$ /i/$1 [L,NC]
```