# How externally redirect url using htaccess, when url contain space, number or dash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, external, space

I am new in htacces.

I want to create htaccess like stackoverflow.

Check any url of stackoverflow like "[hide file extension in url by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658158/hide-file-extension-in-url-by-htaccess)". If you put .html/.php/.asp/.abc/.xyz anything it will redirect to "[hide file extension in url by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658158/hide-file-extension-in-url-by-htaccess)" only even you put / at last it has no effect

Means I want to say url filename contain any keyboard character and it will redirect externally.

below are my current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# To internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html


# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: @anubhava so I want redirect  
---    /dir/file 1.html to /dir/file 1
---   /dir/file-1.html to /dir/file-1
---  /dir/file-1-2.html to /dir/file-1-2

Comment: @anubhava NOT work for externally redirect.

Comment: @anubhava   
if I write 
http://localhost/folder1/folder2/About-us.html 
and press enter key it will redirect to 
http://localhost/About-us

Comment: @anubhava inside folder2 and all files are also located in same folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111193/discussion-between-nikhil-sheth-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use appropriate ``RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Problem remain same after changes in htaccess file.

Comment: now "http://localhost/folder1/folder2/contact us.html" will redirect to 
"http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder1/folder2/contact us"  OR


"http://localhost/folder1/folder2/About-us.html" redirect to 
"http://localhost/folder1/folder2/folder1/folder2/About-us"

Comment: That's not correct. Above rules are working fine on my Apache. You probably have bad cache in browser or some other conflicting rule.

Comment: please check "http://sahcomputer.com/extra/ht2/About-us" this is live url. write .html in url and see the effect

Comment: It works perfectly fine. `http://sahcomputer.com/extra/ht2/About-us.html` got redirected to `http://sahcomputer.com/extra/ht2/About-us`. You need to clear browser cache.

Comment: check product and product123. In both case I got error.

Comment: Both `http://sahcomputer.com/extra/ht2/product123` and `http://sahcomputer.com/extra/ht2/product` also working fine.

Comment: Ok, it works fine in Mozilla but NOT work in chrome.

anyway Big Thanks to giving so much attention to my query.

Comment: you are simply great.

Answer (score 0):

My final htaccess file with the help of great @anubhava

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/

# To externally redirect /folder1/folder2/file.html to /folder1/folder2/file.html or any extension like .php/.asp/.abcd etc
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+?)\.[a-z0-9]{2,}[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```